# RPA Automation Anywhere date format

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

How can I change the user input date format in Automation Anywhere without changing the system variable format?

Example: the user Input date is `28/05/2018`, the required output is `05/28/2018`.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to use the other built in system variables for day, month, and year. Then you can format a date anyway you want without changing the date system variable.

Comment: I agree. Just get all three in a variable and create the date as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Automation Anywhere bot store has a free metabot package called "Change Date and Time Format" that you can download. This has a DLL built into it called changeDateFormat that takes a "culture" as a variable. If you read up on the documentation for culture variables, you can at least transform it into something like 05.28.2018 and replace the "." with "/".

Please feel free to comment if you need additional help finding the links or using the metabot.

Answer (score 1):

we need to put the current date into one variable and then split the date by using a required delimiter ( /,-,... ) then will get 3 values separately that will be put into three variables like data month yr ... according to our  requirement, we can arrange

Answer (score 0):

I worked out for you a code in G1ANT as it is simpler, the default format is already MM/DD/YYYY and you can read month, date and year separately if you want.

Here, is the example:

```
♥myDate = ⟦datetime⟧10/05/2018 12:4:8
dialog ♥myDate
dialog ♥myDate⟦hour⟧
dialog ♥myDate⟦year⟧
dialog ♥myDate⟦dayofyear⟧
```

Answer (score -1):

I call a VB Script to get 2018-02-01 because the `$Day$` & `$Month$` variables don't give the leading zero on single digit days and months

```
' Returns yesterdays date in yyyy-mm-dd format. 
'
'
Dim yesterdaysDate 
yesterdaysDate = DateAdd("d", -1, Now())

Dim result
result = Year(yesterdaysDate) & "-" & Right("0" & Month(yesterdaysDate), 2) _
                              & "-" & Right("0" & Day(yesterdaysDate), 2)

WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(result)
```